# Deleting Objects in State While Rendering State in Reverse

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making a comment section for a website and I ran into a big problem. Currently I have a delete button that splices the comments from state based on their index. I need to show the array in reverse to the user--so when they make multiple comments the newest one is ontop.

The problem is if I reverse() the mapped array the index doesn't get reversed with it, so clicking delete for item 1 deletes the last item, and vice versa.

```
const [userComments, setUserComments] = useState([])

const postComment = (event, userComment) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    setUserComments(prevState => ([...prevState, {comment: userComment}]))
  }
}

const deleteComment = (e, i) => {
  const userCommentsArray = [...userComments]
  userCommentsArray.splice(i, 1)
  setUserComments(prevState => ([...prevState], userCommentsArray))
}

return (
  <input 
  placeholder="Add a public comment" 
  onKeyUp={event => postComment(event, event.currentTarget.value)}
  onClick={event => showCommentButtons()}
  />
  { userComments 
    ? userComments.map((item, i) => (
      <div className="button" onClick={e => deleteComment(e, i)}>Button</div>
      <p className="comment">{item.comment}</p>
    ))
    : null
  }
)
```

Comment: Don't the comments have some identity of their own? If not, start by building `comments.map((comment, index) => ({ ...comment, index }))` then reverse *that*.

Comment: Your comments should have an `id` associated with each of them which will help you to track the comment and also help React in selective DOM update. Using array index to identify a comment is a very bad idea.

Comment: @AkshitMehra Wanted to do this, but couldn't figure it out. What would be a way to generate a random id for them that could also be looked up and deleted from state via a function?

Comment: @RobertC You can use the `uuid` package for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Used unshift to push the items to state in reverse order.

No other changes necessary.

```
  const postComment = (userComment) => {
    const userCommentNotBlank = !userComment.trim().length < 1
    if (userCommentNotBlank) {
      const newState = [...userComments]
      newState.unshift(userComment)
      setUserComments(prevState => ([...prevState], newState))
      resetAddComment()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reverse method on array:

```
const deleteComment = (e, i) => {
  const userCommentsArray = [...userComments].reverse()
  userCommentsArray.splice(i, 1)
  setUserComments(prevState => ([...prevState], userCommentsArray.reverse()))
}
```

Comment: Check the postComment function. Comments get sent to state in normal order, so using this suggestion reverses all user comments at once. Would need to figure out how to also push the comments to state in reverse.

Comment: How about reversing them before setting the state after deleting.